# PM2 errored when Vagrant is reloaded or restarted

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, pm2

I am using vagrant machine and pm2. I have created start up script using:

```
pm2 update ubuntu
```

and then dumped all the running process by

```
pm2 save
```

However when I reload the vagrant machine by vagrant reload. All the process have the following status:

[image]

And if I update it using

```
pm2 update
```

all the process go back online. If I kill and resurrect all the process even then go back online as well. **It is only when the vagrant is restarted it gives the error.**

PM2 logs give the following error

```
Error: spawn node ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:179:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:345:16)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:455:9)
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:410:17)
```

I have tried all the possible solution I could fine none worked so far.

**NOTE:** The same procedure works perfectly when the **host Ubuntu machine** is restarted.

Comment: Any news about this issue? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Nope. Spent a great deal of time on the issue but could not find any satisfactory answer. Please do let me know if you find the answer to it.

Comment: I am also having this exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found this questions while looking for the same problem. Eventually I realized the problem is that the PM2 start-up scripts are executing before Vagrant has mounted your shared directory. So, PM2 is failing to find your scripts when it restarts. This is why it works when Vagrant has finished and you SSH in and rerun PM2. By then, Vagrant has remounted your shared directory. One way I found to get around this is to use rsync instead, this way the files are already on the VM when the restart happens.

Answer (score -1):

As Jason's answer states, this is caused by the order of loading and mounting shared directories.

The basic solution is to use vagrant's shell provisioning, by adding something similar to the following to your vagrant file (after the part where you handle mounting the shared directories):

`config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "pm2 start /vagrant/project/server/index.js && pm2 startup", :run => 'always', privileged: false`

This will cause Vagrant to run this line whenever `vagrant up` is called, this is guaranteed by the `:run => 'always'` option, which means this runs all the time, not just on `vagrant provision` which is the default setting for `config.vm.provision`

Source:  [PM2 on vagrant - starting app AFTER shared folder is mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202390/pm2-on-vagrant-starting-app-after-shared-folder-is-mounted)