# PM2 on vagrant - starting app AFTER shared folder is mounted

Tags: node.js, vagrant, pm2

How can I set PM2 to start the app after the shared directories get mounted? By default `pm2 startup` adds script which try to run script right after OS boot, which causes program error (because the folder is not yet mounted by that time).

Comment: how do you start your app ? by default if you use any provisioning from vagrant, they will run after the shared folder are mounted, you can see from output of running `vagrant up`, you will see _Mounting shared folders..._ before any provisioning step

Comment: the app in pm2 logs has following error: `index-0 (err): chdir(): No such file or directory` which appears on vagrant boot so I'm guessing that it's caused by not mounted folders. After manual `pm2 stop` and  `pm2 start` it's running flawlessly

Comment: **how do you start your app ?** do you have init script, through vagrant provision ...

Comment: No I don't. I'm starting the app manually by using cd /vagrant/project/ && npm start (which starts /vagrant/project/server/index.js). I set up pm2 by command: `pm2 start /vagrant/project/server/index.js` and used `pm2 startup` but the result is explained above

Comment: so when you do `cd /vagrant` you're pointing to a shared folder so it is correctly mounted. The issue is not with shared folder being mounted

Comment: Yes it is. I'm using cd/vagrant/project through ssh long time after machine boots, so the directories are already mounted

Comment: The same problem is well described here: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2036

Comment: right - I told you about provisioning before, I will be like the other guy and tend to use provisioning for this too

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is how to use it correctly. I'm newbie in this kind of problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116479/discussion-between-frederic-henri-and-user1100671).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can add the following line in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "pm2 start /vagrant/project/server/index.js && pm2 startup", :run => 'always', privileged: false
```

read about [shell provisioning](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html)  :

> - inline (string) - Specifies a shell command inline to execute on the remote machine.

This is where you will enter the command lines as you enter them when you ssh into the box

> - `privileged` (boolean) - Specifies whether to execute the shell script as a privileged user or not (sudo). By default this is "true".

In your case, set to `false` so vagrant user will run this command

> By default, provisioners are only run once, during the first vagrant up since the last `vagrant destroy`, unless the `--provision` flag is set, as noted above.
>
> Optionally, you can configure provisioners to run on every `up` or `reload`. They will only be not run if the `--no-provision` flag is explicitly specified. To do this set the `run` option to "always"

setting as `always` so it pm2 will kick off anytime your boot your VM

If you want to run multiple commands you can also write it like

```
config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
    pm2 start /vagrant/project/server/index.js
    pm2 startup
    .... any command that you want to execute ....
  SHELL
```

Comment: Since it's a problem of compatibility pm2 with vagrant it's more like workaround rather than the solution of problem, but still it fixes the issue so I mark this answer as accepted. Thank you sir